# Error TS6266: Build:Option 'listFilesOnly' can only be specified on command line

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-devops, tsconfig, azureportal

I encounter this error when building my React app using an Azure DevOps build pipeline. Any ideas on how to resolve it? I tried updating my tsconfig to include the `"exclude": ["node_modules"]` and `"skipLibCheck": true` properties, but still the error persists..

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: To narrow down the cause of the issue, what is the command that you run on your local machine (without using pipeline)? Does it reproduce the same error?

Comment: Locally it works with no issue, I am using the ap commands documented here for building my project https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to update my `.csproj` to use `ReactTsConfig` instead of `Content` for any `tsconfig.json` files that were in nested folders:

```cs
<Content Include="tsconfig.json" />
<ReactTSConfig Include="path\to\folder\tsconfig.json" />
```